# How to filter obj that doe not have certain value in angular?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-filters

I want to do ng-repeat on an array of objects. I want to the object with color property not equals to "black" to display. How would I do it?

Answer (score 3):

Next time... show a little bit of work:

```
<div data-ng-repeat="thing in stuff | filter:{'color': '!black'}">
    {{ thing}}
</div>
```

JSFiddle with example: http://jsfiddle.net/muwgsxbw/